# Is it possible to generate code properly through a toolbox custom control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, code-generation, toolbox

Ok, so long story short, I was working on a .NET WEBFORMS project which was capable of creating ASPX pages through an ASPX form, which was basically a drag and drop controls page which, we could say, seemed to be a basic but functionality acceptable page/wizard/aspx-creator.

Well, now my higher-ups decided that approach is not a worthy solution and, I don't know why, they got into their heads that this, instead of this ASPX creator form, could be implemented through custom controls added to the toolbox.

So, my doubt is... is that even possible? Or better, is that a reasonable solution? I mean, the first cons I've already found is the fact It seems that it's impossible to yield CodeBehind code by the drag and drop method.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean creating application code, as in business logic such as `if(BossIsMoody) { DoMoreWork(); }` or just the basic initialization?

Comment: I heard there is a better extension to the DoMoreWork method, its the CheckBossLocation method, if the boss is nearby it fires the do more work method else it fires the ViewCatPictures method

Comment: I mean, adding an big chunks of code, which in many cases involves tracking all the controls dropped and where and many more complicated situations that I doubt I can deal this way :(

Comment: wait you just want to be able to paste large bits of code? if you highlight the code you want, drag it over the toolbox and drop it, it will show up as a little scroll with your code in it, when you want to paste that in yu just drag and drop like you would any control.

Comment: I could give it a try, but there's a hole in all this: the code is not always the same and has to be loaded dynamically depending on what I dragged before and so. But, hey, it's worth to give it a shot  thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[Custom Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhzc935f.aspx)

This MDSN walkthrough teaches you aboutmaking custom web controlls for asp. these would be able to appear in your tool box and could be dragged into its respective place, is this waht you are looking for?

EDIT: 
Re-reading it looks like you want to be able to drag in bits of code and have certain regions prompted for edits, this CAN be done, using snippets. if you type propg or propfull and tab twice it constructs that code and tells you what bits to edit right? you can make your own snippets!
[Creating custom snippets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165393%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
failful msdn tutorials to the rescue once more!

Comment: Sort of... but I don't know if it's straightforward or powerful enough to deal with the issues a have to deal with :( but thanks for your comment

Comment: @Painy James ive updated my answer, it may be more useful to you now!